# constant value is coming as an infinity in the solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the differential equation $du/dt = P(u(t))$ where $P$ is any polynomial of degree greater than or equal to 2 with initial condition $u(0)=1$.
By existence and uniqueness theorem, this IVP has a solution in some neighbourhood of $0$.  
But if we take $P(x) = (x-1)^3$ and substituted in given equation, we get
$\frac{1}{-2(u-1)^2}=t+C$ which gives $C=\infty$ using $u(0)=1$, which means there doesn't exist any solution, which is contradicting Existence theorem.
What's going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You divided by $(u-1)^3$, you can only do that at times $t$ where $u(t) \ne 1$. So letting $t = 0$ afterwards is a bad idea ...

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables comes with some assumptions - like the integral
$$
\int^{x}_{1}\frac{1}{(s-1)^3}~\mathrm{d}s
$$
may not have a singularity that we integrate over - which is the case here.

This is because those singularities are obviously constant solutions. Just check that $u(t) = 1$ solves your ODE. The existence theorem is not contradicted in any way.